# MAX and GROUP BY don't return good values

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

After searching for a couple of hours on the website, I couldn't find the right answer to my problem, or the answer was too complicated.
I have some statistics, from a minecraft server and I want to know which blocks are created the most by whom. So I started with `GROUP BY` and `MAX`, but it didn't return the right values. The `MAX` value is good, but it conflicts with the `itemid` and the `playerid`. It just selects the first id and playername. (NOTE: each playerid has a seperate row for each item!!!) The query is as following:

```
SELECT  `playername` ,  `itemid` , MAX( destroyed ) 
FROM  `blockstats_typed` 
GROUP BY  `itemid` 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The fields that are there are `playername`, `itemid`, `created` and `destroyed`. I hope you guys can help me...

If you need more info, just say so!

Edit 1 (Table schema):

```
id          int(10)         id of the row (AI)
playername  varchar(50)     playername
itemid      smallint(5)     id of the item
created     int(10)         times created
destroyed   int(10)         times destroyed
```

Comment: you need to group by `playername` as well.  I'm surprised that didn't error out.

Comment: Only MySQL (and PostgreSQL, but in a much more limited way) allows you to omit columns (expressions) from the GROUP BY clause that are in the select-list but not aggregates.  If you want the item ID, the maximum number of times it was destroyed, and the user ID (or IDs) that did that, you have to write a more complex query.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: SQLite does the MySQL "pick a random one" thing, PostgreSQL let's you get away with it if you're grouping by the PK and using version 9.1+ (AFAIK on both).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Now it just returns 2 values, but I want of all the 124 possible id's to return which playername destroyed the most of that id.

Comment: You're going to need to post the table schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only MySQL and PostgreSQL (but PostgreSQL does it in a much more limited way; *and a comment tells me that SQLite mimics MySQL in this*) allow you to omit columns (expressions) from the GROUP BY clause that are in the select-list but are not aggregates. If you want the item ID, the maximum number of times it was destroyed, and the user ID (or IDs) that did that, you have to write a more complex query.

So, you might be after:

```
SELECT playername,  itemid, MAX(destroyed) 
  FROM blockstats_typed
 GROUP BY playername, itemid 
 LIMIT 0, 30
```

Or you might be after:

```
SELECT b.PlayerName, s.ItemID, s.MaxDestroyed
  FROM BlockStats_Typed AS b
  JOIN (SELECT ItemID, MAX(Destroyed) AS MaxDestroyed
          FROM BlockStats_Typed
         GROUP BY ItemID
         LIMIT 0, 30
       ) AS s
    ON b.ItemID = s.ItemID AND b.Destroyed = s.MaxDestroyed;
```

Note that if some item is destroyed, say, 237,000 times by two players, you will get back both players' names (if that ItemID is in the top 30, of course).

Both are valid queries; they do different things, though.  You'll have to decide which, if either, is correct for what you're trying to do.  And if neither is correct, you probably need to clarify your question.

(I'm not certain that the LIMIT is allowed where I've written it.  If not, place it at the end.  And you might want to add an ORDER BY clause with a DESC qualifier to ensure that the limit clause shows the most interesting rows; GROUP BY does not guarantee sorting.)

Comment: This did the trick, thank you very much! I will give you the credit for it, hope the users will appreciate it! :)